# Setting up mailserver with relay host

Tags: postfix

So the port 25 on my mailserver is blocked and I'm now trying to set up my mail server with a SMTP relay to send mail with dynu.com. But i keep getting the error messages bellow when i try to send a mail from the 
terminal window.

In master.cf I have set the following

```
465 inet n - n - - smtpd
```

In main.cf I have set this

```
myhostname = rajohan.no
mydestination = localhost, rajohan.no, localhost.rajohan.no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password

relayhost = [relay.dynu.com]:465
smtpd_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

In sasl_password i have

```
relay.dynu.com
relay@relay.rajohan.no mypassword
```

In generic i have

```
mail@rajohan.no         mail@rajohan.no
postbot@rajohan.no      postbot@rajohan.no
webmaster@rajohan.no    webmaster@rajohan.no
postmaster@rajohan.no   webmaster@rajohan.no
root@rajohan.no         webmaster@rajohan.no
root@mail.rajohan.no    webmaster@rajohan.no
abuse@rajohan.no        webmaster@rajohan.no
hostmaster@rajohan.no   webmaster@rajohan.no
```

> Dec 19 22:22:49 rajohan dovecot: imap-login: Login:
>   user=, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1,
>   mpid=30452, secured, session=<6DQx6LhgdJZ/AAAB>
>
> Dec 19 22:22:49 rajohan dovecot: imap(mail@rajohan.no): Logged out in=50 out=490
>
> Dec 19 22:22:57 rajohan postfix/pickup[30405]: AEF3884669: uid=0
>   from=
>
> Dec 19 22:22:57 rajohan postfix/cleanup[30461]: warning:
>   connect to Milter service unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory
>
> Dec 19 22:22:57 rajohan postfix/cleanup[30461]: AEF3884669: message-id=<20171219222257.AEF3884669@rajohan.no>
>
> Dec 19 22:22:57 rajohan postfix/qmgr[30406]: AEF3884669: from=, size=284, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 19 22:22:57 rajohan postfix/smtp[30467]: SMTPS wrappermode (TCP port 465) requires setting "smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes", and "smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt" (or stronger)
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/smtp[30467]: AEF3884669: to=rajohan1@gmail.com>, relay=relay.dynu.com[199.233.237.19]:465, delay=23, delays=21/0.08/1.3/0.33, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host relay.dynu.com[199.233.237.19] said: 530 SMTP authentication is
>   required. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/cleanup[30461]: BFE7E84668: message-id=<20171219222259.BFE7E84668@rajohan.no>
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/qmgr[30406]: BFE7E84668: from=<>, size=2190, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/trivial-rewrite[30462]: warning: do not list domain rajohan.no in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/bounce[30470]: AEF3884669: sender non-delivery notification: BFE7E84668
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/qmgr[30406]: AEF3884669: removed
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/local[30471]: BFE7E84668: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "webmaster")
>
> Dec 19 22:22:59 rajohan postfix/qmgr[30406]: BFE7E84668: removed

Comment: Typically you should use port 587. Port 465 may also be blocked along with port 25. If they have not yet done so, they will do it sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sasl_password file should be formatted like this and match that of the `relayhost` directive:

`[host]:Port USERNAME:PASSWORD`

So, your's would look like this:

`[relay.dynu.com]:465 relay@relay.rajohan.no:mypassword`

Then you need to hash the file:
`sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_password`

Now, you have a file created: `/etc/postfix/sasl_password.db`

Change the following directives in your `main.cf` (remove the d):

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
```

Don't forget to restart postfix.

[Configuring SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP/LMTP client](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but my solution was to change main.cf:

```
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

And restart Postfix